# Redirect to url, If Jwplayer error loading media

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, jwplayer

I embedded JWPlayer on my page but sometime video cant loaded, someone can help me how to make redirect to new url if jwplayer cant load file

This is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('player').setup({
        file: 'http://blog.com/stream.m3u8',
        image: 'http://blog.com/streamimage.png',
        title: 'STREAMING TITLE',
        width: '100%',
        height: "100%",
        aspectratio: '16:9',
        skin: 'glow',
        mute: 'true',
        ga: '{}'
    });
</script>
```

this code for change source video, but i need make it to redirect to new url use header location

```
jwplayer().onError(function(){    jwplayer().load({file:"http://jwplayer.com/errorfile.mp4",
image:"http://blog.com/streamimage-error.png"}); //
       });
```

like this:

```
 <?php header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); ?> /* Redirect browser */
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

To redirect using javascript, you use :

```
window.location.href = 'http://wherever';
```